# Android Keystore KeyPairGeneratorSpec Where do I get X500Principal

Tags: android, android-keystore

I am building a keystore that I will hide my authorization and refresh tokens in. I am on API 19. Looking at the examples for KeyPairGeneratorSpec. Most of the examples use a dummy certificate (X500Principal). I haven't worked much with certificates. I am not sure where I get this "subject." Is this the certificate used in the generation of a signed APK?  IE https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html
Or do I get a certificate from a group like CA?

That said once I have this data, how do I transform it into this X500? How do I map the data to the x500?

The former will be problematic due to the way my company is handling app signing.  I am not sure I will have access to it.

Following

```
KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(this)
                        .setAlias(k)
                        .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=Sample Name, O=Android Authority"))
                        .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
                        .setStartDate(start.getTime())
                        .setEndDate(end.getTime())
                        .build();
KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signing your .apk for distribution on the Google Play Store and encrypting sensitive user data using the AndroidKeyStore are distinct. The former takes place using the Java Key Store (jks) on your dev machine (i.e. your laptop or desktop computer) while the other takes place on the handset where your app is installed.

You don't need to obtain a certificate authority for the [X500Principal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/auth/x500/X500Principal.html). The example code you quoted is correct and you would just substitute it with, for example, your application name and organisation:

```
new X500Principal("CN=StarWind, O=StarWindOrganization");
```

If you want to understand what the different abbreviations mean, please refer to the [Wikipedia entry for Lightweight Directory Access Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol#Directory_structure) but just for instance, "CN" means "common name" and "O" means organisation. The attributes you supply here are merely to form a unique entry much in the same way you form a unique package name in Java like `com.starwind.myapp`.

If you are finding it confusing you can have a look at [Scytale](https://github.com/yakivmospan/scytale) which is a wrapper around the Android KeyStore. Even if you don't end up using the library, the code there is quite useful for working out how to use the KeyStore.